# jQuery issue showing images (won't show, or disappears quickly)

Tags: jquery, html, image, hide, show

I'm trying to make a simple website. I want to show the thumbnails of images, and then the user can click on the thumbnail to show a bigger picture. The thumbnails have been given an id, and the larger pictures have been given a class - the same name. MOST of them work, except for two (leaders and sealions). At first just the leaders didn't show, and the sealions would show and then disappear really quickly. I can't figure this out, considering that all the code looks the same, and yes, all the image names are correct. My jQuery:

```
$("#beach").click(function() {
    $("#big img").hide();
    $(".beach").show("slow");
});
$("#cherry").click(function() {
    $("#big img").hide();
    $(".cherry").show("slow");
});
$("#coit").click(function() {
    $("#big img").hide();
    $(".coit").show("slow");
});

$("#dmz").click(function() {
    $("#big img").hide();
    $(".dmz").show("slow");
});
$("#leaders").click(function() {
    $("#big img").hide();
    $(".leaders").show("slow");
});
$("#nkcoast").click(function() {
    $("#big img").hide();
    $(".nkcoast").show("slow");
});
$("#nkhike").click(function() {
    $("#big img").hide();
    $(".nkhike").show("slow");
});
$("#san").click(function() {
    $("#big img").hide();
    $(".san").show("slow");
});
$("#sealions").click(function(){
    $("#big img").hide();
    $(".sealions").show("slow");
});
$("#mail").click(function(){
    $("#big img").hide();
    $(".mail").show("slow");
});
$("#towers").click(function() {
    $("#big img").hide();
    $(".towers").show("slow");
});
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="thumbs">
<img src="images/beachthumb.jpg" id="beach">
<img src="images/cherryblossomthumb.jpg" id= "cherry">
<img src="images/coittowerthumb.png" id="coit">
<img src="images/dmzthumb.jpg" id="dmz">
<img src="images/leadersthumb.jpg" id="leaders">
    <img src="images/nkcoastthumb.jpg" id="nkcoast">
<img src="images/nkhikethumb.jpg" id="nkhike">
<img src="images/sanvicentethumb.jpg" id="san">
<img src="images/sealionsthumb.png" id="sealions">
<img src="images/tokyomailthumb.jpg" id="mail">
<img src="images/towersthumb.jpg" id="towers">
</div>

<div id="big">
<img src="images/nkhike.jpg" class="nkhike">
<img src="images/tokyomail.jpg" class="mail">
<img src="images/sanvicente.jpg" class="san">
<img src="images/beach.jpg" class="beach">
<img src="images/nkcoast.jpg" class="nkcoast">
<img src="images/leaders.jpg" class"leaders">
<img src="images/towers.jpg" class="towers">
<img src="images/dmz.jpg" class="dmz">
<img src="images/sealions.png" class="sealions">
<img src="images/coittower.png" class="coit">
<img src="images/cherryblossom.jpg" class="cherry">
</div>
```

And yes, I've looked around and can't find help to this question.

Comment: Why are leaders and sealions using `.fadeIn()` when the others use `.show()`?

Comment: Good question. I had tried to change some things to fadeIn instead of show to see if it would help. I forgot to change it back before I posted it here.

Comment: I guess my main question is WHY doesn't this code work for those two images when they work just fine for the others? and WHY does one just not show while the other one shows and then disappears quickly? That's what I don't get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simpler solution, <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/r7mFt/)**</kbd>

Replace `id` with HTML5 `data` attribute

```
<div id="thumbs">
  <img src="images/beachthumb.jpg" data-rel="beach">
  <img src="images/cherryblossomthumb.jpg" data-rel="cherry">
  <img src="images/coittowerthumb.png" data-rel="coit">
  <img src="images/dmzthumb.jpg" data-rel="dmz">
  <img src="images/leadersthumb.jpg" data-rel="leaders">
  <img src="images/nkcoastthumb.jpg" data-rel="nkcoast">
  <img src="images/nkhikethumb.jpg" data-rel="nkhike">
  <img src="images/sanvicentethumb.jpg" data-rel="san">
  <img src="images/sealionsthumb.png" data-rel="sealions">
  <img src="images/tokyomailthumb.jpg" data-rel="mail">
  <img src="images/towersthumb.jpg" data-rel="towers">
</div>

<div id="big">
  <img src="images/nkhike.jpg" class="nkhike" alt="Nkhike">
  <img src="images/tokyomail.jpg" class="mail" alt="Mail">
  <img src="images/sanvicente.jpg" class="san" alt="San">
  <img src="images/beach.jpg" class="beach" alt="Beach">
  <img src="images/nkcoast.jpg" class="nkcoast" alt="Nkcoast">
  <img src="images/leaders.jpg" class="leaders" alt="Leaders">
  <img src="images/towers.jpg" class="towers" alt="Towers">
  <img src="images/dmz.jpg" class="dmz" alt="Dmz">
  <img src="images/sealions.png" class="sealions" alt="Sealions">
  <img src="images/coittower.png" class="coit" alt="Coit">
  <img src="images/cherryblossom.jpg" class="cherry" alt="Cherry">
</div>
```

Demo style

```
#big img {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}
#big img:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

and little bit of jQuery

```
(function($) {
  $('#thumbs img').click(function() {
    $('#big img[class="'+$(this).data('rel')+'"]').fadeIn(400, 'linear').siblings('img').fadeOut(400, 'linear');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This is interesting, thank you. I'm trying hard to make this page on my own, so I need to study this a bit to make sure I understand. Thanks for your time!

Comment: But can you see a reason why mine DOESN'T work? I mean, am I missing something as to why two of them just don't work even though their code looks just like the others? AFter typing all of the jquery out for every single one I realized that a function or variables or something would be a better way to handle it. I'm just confused as to why mine doesn't work.

Comment: For example you miss equal sign in class name `<img src="images/leaders.jpg" class"leaders">`, other than that your code works just fine but it's a bit overkill to write code like that.

Comment: Thank yoU! Duh. Also, still don't know why the sea lions picture was doing the quick appear/disappear business, but I tried your code and it works! Thank you so much! I don't want to do the 600px by 400px because some pictures are vertical, and it compresses them. I also want to center the pictures within the div, so I will work on that. Thank you so much for your time and help.

Comment: You're welcome ;) To center the images, put gallery in wrapper div and set `text-align: center;` to mentioned div.